# How would you create a modal that does not "tab" anything?

Tags: bootstrap-modal

So I am creating a simple version of the mcdonald's site as a part of a project that I am doing, and in that, I need to add a modal that displays a map on the click of a button. However, when I add the modal, the positions of the elements that are already in place are disturbed.

I am trying to figure out how to add to modal without having the other elements move, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

The modal is supposed to show up with the click of the button with the class "location".

I have included the code snippet and screenshots to let you know what the project was like before and after the modal, to let you see what I mean by the positioning being disturbed.

Here is code that the problem occurs with:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Crimson+Text&family=Graduate&family=Shadows+Into+Light&display=swap');

*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html,body{
    width:100vw;
    height:100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.container nav{
    width:100vw;
    height:15vh;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background:red;
}
nav img{
    width:6vw;
    height:auto;
    margin-left:3vw;
}
nav #button{
    padding: 1.8vh 2vw;
    margin-right:4vw;
    background:linear-gradient(to right, gold, yellow);
    border:.1px solid black;
    border-radius:0.390625vw;
    color:black;
    font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:1.125vw;
}
nav #button:hover{
    background:linear-gradient(to right, goldenrod, rgb(161, 161, 0));
}
.container .orderbar{
    width:100vw;
    height:13vh;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);
    display:flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    font-family:'Shadows Into Light',cursive;
}

.orderbar #fafaicon{
    font-size:2.109375vw;
    color:#999999;
    vertical-align: center;
    margin-top:4vh;
}
.orderbar #fafaicon:hover{
    color:white;
}
.orderbar a{
    text-decoration:none;
}


.icon{
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 2.109375vw;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: 'Shadows Into Light',cursive;
    background:none;
    border:none;
}
.icon:hover{
    color:white;
}
i{
    padding-left: 3vw;
}
i span{
    font-family: 'Shadows Into Light',cursive;
    margin-left:.5vw;
}
.orderbar .right{
    margin-right:4vw;
}
.orderbar .location{
    padding: 1.6420361247947455vh 1.953125vw;
    font-family: 'Graduate',cursive;
}
.location{
    font-size:1.328125vw;
    margin-top:-2vh;
    border-radius: 1.796875vw;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    color:#999999;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
}
.location:hover{
    background-color: #999999;
    color:black;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>McDonald's</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!--Clickable Map Modal-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Icons -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://site-assets.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.1.2/css/all.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">

        <!--Ad Swiper-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.css"/>

        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="container">
            <nav>
                <img src="/Assets/McDonalds.png"/>
                <button id="button">Sign In</button>
            </nav>
            <div class="orderbar">
                <div class="left">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="link">
                            <button class="icon">
                                <i class="fa fa-truck" id="fafaicon"><span>Delivery</span></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="link">
                            <button class="icon" >
                                <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag" id="fafaicon"><span>Takeout</span></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </a>    
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="link">  
                            <button class="icon">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-plate-utensils" id="fafaicon"><span>Dine-In</span></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </a>   
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="link">
                            <button class="icon">
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-receipt" id="fafaicon"><span>Menu</span></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </a> 
                        
                </div>
                <div class="right">
                    <button class="location" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#map">Our Location</button>
                    <button class="icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-search" id="fafaicon"></i></button>
                    <button class="icon" href="#"><i class="fa fa-cart-shopping-fast" id="fafaicon"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="map" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3507.9651108961293!2d-81.47361158255616!3d28.450468100000002!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x88e77e5534ccb6bb%3A0x7e45cfcb49c75afa!2sMcDonald&#39;s!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sca!4v1661213105618!5m2!1sen!2sca" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <script src="https://unpkg.com/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Project Screenshots**

Notice how there is no whitespace and everything lines up with the edges:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qtDr.png)

Notice the space on the left:

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCTKx.jpg)

Comment: The modal itself will not shift the position of elements on the DOM... by "*the elements in the background automatically tab and move right from their original positions*" are you meaning the code indentation itself? If that's the case, you need to specify which editor you're using.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your reply!

Sorry I am new so I am new so I am not sure if the code indentation is the code itself, or if it is what is displayed when the code is executed. However, I can provide a screenshot of my actual project if that helps.

Also, the editor is Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I copied your code and run it and I didn't see any problem. The screenshot you provided don't give us any useful information, because that part is not in the code that you provided. Please edit you code and post it as 'code snippet' first, after provide more information about your project that let us help you.